# create geometry using points from other meshes in the scene

Tags: three.js, 3d, geometry

I am looking to create a wedge shape using other geometry that can be manipulated by the user.

[image: Diagram of a wedge shape labeled with points, objects and planes]

- The height, width and z rotation of **Cylinder** can be changed by the user
- The angle of **Plane A** can be change by the user
- I want to create a wedge shape using **Points A** through **F**.

What is the best way to determine the **Points A** through **F** so that I can use them to create a [ConvexGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/geometries/ConvexGeometry)? Or is there a different method for creating this geometry?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? There's a pretty easy to follow example on the [documentation for BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry).

Comment: @Marquizzo sorry I wasn't clear, but I'm not asking for help in building the geometry but asking for help in how to get the points to use in building the geometry. So far what I've tried is using the `position` of the cylinder offset by its length / 2 to get the points at the ends but it felt ... somewhat inefficient. I'm not sure how to approach this. For example, where the to planes intersect for Point E and F, is there a way to get that using the two planes or do I need to raycast or something?